# Can splitting template specializations between multiple files lead to ODR violations?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, template-specialization, one-definition-rule

I wrote a parser class that contains base functionality for other, type specific parsers. For example, it contains a function to create an enum value from a string.

I didn't want the base class to contain information about the specific types, so I've implemented it as a template and used a trait to avoid including type specific headers:

```
// ParserBase.h
#include "EnumTrait.h"
template<typename EnumT>
EnumT parseEnum(std::string str)
{
  return traits::EnumTrait<EnumT>::fromString(str);
}
```

The `EnumTrait` template is defined like so:

```
// EnumTrait.h
namespace traits
{
template<typename T>
struct EnumTrait
{
  static_assert(sizeof(T) == -1, "Specialization not found");
};
} // namespace traits
```

Now, in each header where my enums are defined, there is also a specialization for this template. For example:

```
// Enum_A.h
#include "EnumTrait.h"
namespace A
{
enum class Enum_A
{
  A
};
Enum_A fromString(std::string) {return Enum_A::A;}
} // namespace A

namespace traits
{
template<>
struct EnumTrait<A::Enum_A>
{
  static std::string fromString(std::string str){ return A::fromString(str); }
};
// namespace traits
```

Headers for other enums look similar.

The usage of the base function:

```
// Enum_AParser.cpp
#include "ParserBase.h"
#include "Enum_A.h"
// ...
Enum_A foo = parseEnum<Enum_A>(bar);
// ...
```

My concern is: can this (does it) lead to ODR violations (or some other problems)?

It's impossible to use the trait with `Enum_A` and not have the specialization for it available, as they are defined in the same header.

But is it ok to not have every template specialization available in every TU where the template is used (for example Enum_A will not be available in the Enum_BParser)?

One thing I've noticed while thinking about this is that it is legal to create our own specializations of templates available in the standard library, so maybe it is ok after all?

I am using C++17, if that changes anything.

Comment: The generic version can be simpler: `template<typename T> struct EnumTrait;` - declaration but no definition.

Comment: I don't see any particular ODR problem here (although I think `-1`, even after conversion to unsigned, might technically be outside of the value range of `sizeof` and thus be ill-formed, no diagnostic required - but I wouldn't worry about it). Might I recommend the [tag:language-lawyer] tag?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Thanks for the suggestion. I guess with the `static_assert` the error message is a bit clearer, though.
@MaxLanghof I guess I can change it to `0`, thanks for that. I'll add the language-lawyer tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks OK to me. It is not required that every specialization be visible in every translation unit. It is only required that the specialization be declared before every use of the template that would otherwise trigger an implicit instantiation.

> [**[temp.expl.spec]/7**](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.spec#temp.expl.spec-7) If a template, a member template or a member of a class template is explicitly specialized then that specialization shall be declared before the first use of that specialization that would cause an implicit instantiation to take place, in every translation unit in which such a use occurs; no diagnostic is required...